# Firebase functions - multiple vs single

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Firebase providing the way to write multiple independent functions.

Does it affect the cost?

Does it affect performance if REST client will use keep-alive connection to one function vs multiple (same domain)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it affect the cost?

No.  You pay per invocation, not per deployment.

> Does it affect performance if REST client will use keep-alive connection to one function vs multiple (same domain)?

No.

Comment: What about coordinating deployments? One function faster to deploy without coordinating versioning?